# Unable to install NuGet package provider in PowerShell Core on Linux

Tags: nuget, powershell-core

I'm trying to set up the NuGet package provider on Linux in PowerShell 7 so I can use
`Install-Package` to get a package from the NuGet Gallery. However, when I run:

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force
```

I get the following error:

```
Install-PackageProvider: No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'NuGet'.
The package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified
package has the tags.
```

I did a bit of searching and found a few questions from this site and others where this error occurs, some answers saying I need to force TLS 1.2:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

some saying to specify `-RequiredVersion` on `Install-PackageSource`, some saying to use
`-ForceBootstrap`, and some saying to use `-Force`. None of these work and I'm still met with the same error each time. `Get-PackageProvider` lists NuGet as a provider.

I'm was also unable to install the NuGet provider on Windows using PowerShell Core with the same error. Is this just not supported from PowerShell Core?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also received this error and specifying the version (currently 3.0.0.1) also fails. What worked for me was piping the packageprovider into `Install-PackageProvider`

```
Get-PackageProvider | where name -eq 'nuget' | Install-PackageProvider
```

You may add `-Force` if you want to avoid answering yes to `The package(s) come(s) from a package source that is not marked as trusted. Are you sure you want to install software from ''?`

Comment: Thanks, this got me halfway where I needed to be to install packages. Once I got the provider installed I still had to register the package source as well.

Comment: `Get-PackageProvider | where name -eq 'nuget' | Install-PackageProvider -Force` gives me the following error: _"Install-PackageProvider: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'input')"_. Without `-Force` it works, but gives me the mentioned confirmation promt.

Answer (score 4):

The NuGet location has been updated. You can also do it in one line:

```
Register-PackageSource -Name nuget.org -ProviderName NuGet -Location "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" -Trusted
```

Comment: I got this. `Register-PackageSource : Unable to find package providers (NuGet).`

Answer (score 3):

Having TLS12 set in conjunction with Install Nuget package worked for me.

Below is how I used the command:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@DougMaurer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63892462/584676), I also had to configure the package source as well:

```
$sourceArgs = @{
  Name = 'nuget.org'
  Location = 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'
  ProviderName = 'NuGet'
}
Register-PackageSource @sourceArgs
```