# Unable to install NuGet package provider on PowerShell Core 7.0.3

Tags: nuget, powershell-core

I have a `PowerShell Core 7.0.3` on **Ubuntu 18.04.**

When trying to install **NuGet** with the following command, it gives the error:

```
PS /home/adp/Downloads> Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
Install-PackageProvider: Unable to find repository with SourceLocation ''. Use Get-PSRepository to see all available repositories.
```

The `Get-PSRepository` command also not working:

```
PS /home/adp/Downloads> Get-PSRepository 
Get-PackageSource: /home/adp/.local/share/powershell/Modules/PowerShellGet/2.1.2/PSModule.psm1:9186
Line |
9186 |  … ckageSources = PackageManagement\Get-PackageSource @PSBoundParameters
     |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Unable to find module providers (PowerShellGet).
```

And, `Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable` returns nothing.

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63856516/unable-to-install-nuget-package-provider-in-powershell-core-on-linux), and it didn't work.

I'm stuck on the problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're saying you tried 
`Get-PackageProvider | where name -eq 'nuget' | Install-PackageProvider

$sourceArgs = @{
  Name = 'nuget.org'
  Location = 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2'
  ProviderName = 'NuGet'
}

Register-PackageSource @sourceArgs`
and it didn't work? What DID it do?

Comment: @DougMaurer many thanks for the answer.  `Get-PackageProvider | where name -eq 'nuget' | Install-PackageProvider` returns `Install-PackageProvider: Unable to find repository with SourceLocation ''. Use Get-PSRepository to see all available repositories.`

Comment: And, 
$sourceArgs = @{
  Name = 'nuget.org'
  Location = 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2'
  ProviderName = 'NuGet'
}
Register-PackageSource @sourceArgs
 returns `Register-PackageSource: Unable to find package providers (NuGet).`

Comment: What does `Get-PackageSource` show?

Comment: It turns `Get-PackageSource: Unable to find package providers ().`

Comment: Oh i see it was called under the hood with Get-PSRepository as well, in your original post. Hmm

Comment: Does this help? Run this before [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work either.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue as @adp on a Windows Server 2012 system with .NET 4.8 and PS 5.1 installed. FIPS is enabled on this system.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the `Modules` folder under `\Documents\WindowsPowershell\` worked for us ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/257840/powershell-unable-to-find-module-providers-powersh.html)).

Answer (score 0):

This is still broken in PSH 7.3.1 and the only way I could get NuGet on my system was by installing it using an older version of PSH which then allowed me to use PSH 7.3.1 to install the Dotnet tools I originally wanted to install.