# Powershell Install-PackageProvider No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'NuGet

Tags: powershell

From a Windows Server 2019 server Ran as Administrator in Powershell window with the following command

```
 Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
```

Got the following error

> WARNING: MSG:UnableToDownload «https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409» «»
> WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet connection.
> WARNING: Unable to download from URI 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''. Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'NuGet'. The package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags.
> At line:1 char:1 Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
> CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider) [Install-Pac
> kageProvider], Exception
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackagePro
> vider

Powershell version is 5.1.17763.2268 and is able to open public website from the machine.  I tried all the suggested solutions I can find online (below) but still getting the same error.  Wondering if there's anything else can be done to fix this issue?

- Setting [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
- Setting [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
- Get-PackageProvider | where name -eq 'nuget' | Install-PackageProvider

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install NuGet package provider in PowerShell Core on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63856516/unable-to-install-nuget-package-provider-in-powershell-core-on-linux)

Comment: @DougMaurer Yes, I have tried all suggested fixes in that link and still not working

Comment: You don’t show that you’ve tried Benders addition (specifying package source) https://stackoverflow.com/a/63893754/4085331

Comment: You can access this url from the server's browser ? https://onegetcdn.azureedge.net/providers/nuget-2.8.5.208.package.swidtag